# Invoke method with specific parameters without type unboxing

Tags: c#, reflection

Right now I'm invoking a method and it works. Here is a sample of what I'm doing:

```
string result = (string)GetType().InvokeMember(actionName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, this, new object[] { userId, roleId, rankId });
```

Invoking the following sample method:

```
    private string UserName(int userId, int roleId, int rankId)
    {
        ...stuff...
        return "JoeDoe";
    }
```

I have multiple methods like `"UserName"` shown here that I'm finding via Reflection but they all have the same signature. 
Can I stay away from type unboxing ? Is there a way for me to pass `{int,int,int}` as parameters in this case for example instead of new object[] ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the method via a delegate, instead of just as a string method name?

Comment: Yes - then you could simply use a Func.

Comment: No.  It is pointless anyway, InvokeMember() is *expensive* compared to a direct call.  That bit of boxing won't make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - using reflection, you'll have to box the values to invoke the member.  However, the cost of reflection itself is quite high, so the boxing operation is not (relatively) expensive in this case.

If you can, instead, make a delegate, you could call the delegate directly:

```
Func<int, int, int, string> del = yourClassInstance.UserName;

// use three ints directly here...
string result = del(user, role, rank);
```

This still allows you to assign various delegates to the different methods, and call them, without the overhead of reflection or boxing.

Comment: I guess that Shenaniganz knows only the method name, which is stored in `actionName` variable.

Comment: @AlexanderBalte There are options, such as a dictionary of string->delegate, which can be used to solve that if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful. I went with using delegates:
(DelegateType)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DelegateType), classInstance, actionName, true);
You're right, delegates can be invoked with their direct parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Reflection using performance overhead is incomparably higher than boxing/unboxing performance overhead.

You should not carry about boxing/unboxing.

Comment: I tend to agree. Unboxing will be very cheap in comparison with Reflection finding your method by name.